# Uploading an image to a folder in desktop

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, upload, directory

I can't get to upload an image to a specified folder. Here's the code.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploader.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
             string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploader.FileName);
             FileUploader.SaveAs(@"D:\Users\SGG90745\Desktop\PICTURES" + filename);
             Label1.Text = "Uploaded Successfully!!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on upload, the label does says `Uploaded Successfully!!` as written in the code but the picture is not in the specified folder in the code. Please help thank you!

Comment: Have you checked the value of filename ? I assume it does not start with a \ - then the provided file name in FileUploader.SaveAs will not store the data inside of the PICTURES folder but in the Desktop-folder with the file name beginning with PICTURES.

Comment: Yes, see your Desktop with file name start with PICTURES____. Is the uploaded file in Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `\` after the PICTURES:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploader.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
             string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploader.FileName);
             FileUploader.SaveAs(@"D:\Users\SGG90745\Desktop\PICTURES\" + filename);
             Label1.Text = "Uploaded Successfully!!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploader.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
             string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploader.FileName);
             FileUploader.SaveAs(@"D:\Users\SGG90745\Desktop\PICTURES\" + filename);
             Label1.Text = "Uploaded Successfully!!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

I have simply added a backslash after PICTURES in order to build the correct file name.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this line:

```
FileUploader.SaveAs(@"D:\Users\SGG90745\Desktop\PICTURES" + filename);
```

Adding a slash would fix it:

```
FileUploader.SaveAs(@"D:\Users\SGG90745\Desktop\PICTURES\" + filename);
```

A more platform-agnostic way to fix it would be:

```
const string folder = @"D:\Users\SGG90745\Desktop\PICTURES" 
...
var path = folder + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + filename;
```

And the best way to do it is:

```
const string folder = @"D:\Users\SGG90745\Desktop\PICTURES" 
...
var path = Path.Combine(folder, filename);
```